# read.table that delete 0 of each rows in r

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file in which every row is a string of numbers. Example of a row: 0234

Example of this file:

```
00020
04921
04622
...
```

When i use read.table it delete all the first 0 of each row (00020 becomes 20, 04921 -> 4921,...). I use:

`example <- read.table(fileName, sep="\t",check.names=FALSE)`

After this, for obtain a vector i use `as.vector(unlist(example))`.

I try different options of read.table but the problem remains

Comment: You can specify `colClasses`

Answer (score 2):

The `read.table` by default checks the column values and change the column type accordingly.  If we want a custom type, specify it with `colClasses`

```
example <- read.table(fileName, sep="\t",check.names=FALSE, 
           colClasses = "character", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When we are not specifying the `colClasses`, the function use `type.convert` to automatically assign the column types based on the value

```
read.table # function
...
...
 data[[i]] <- if (is.na(colClasses[i])) 
        type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, 
            numerals = numerals, na.strings = character(0L))
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you read in your data file with `read.table` but since you want a vector, not a data frame, you then `unlist` the df. And you want to keep the leading zeros.
There is a simpler way of doing the same, use `scan`.

```
example <- scan(file = fileName, what = character(), sep = "\t")
```